# Computing of speech signals modulation entropy

Tags: speech-processing, wave, c++

I got a question regarding to modulation entropy of audio signal. There is some literature I found about this topic, http://www.irit.fr/recherches/SAMOVA/FeaturesExtraction.html#me.

I've read sample .wav file. How do I calculate entropy of this sampled signal of lenght N samples? How should I understand, in this case (in paper equation from above), propability of event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've found what i was looking for.

This paper describes how to measure entropy in signals:

Entropy Based Voice Activity Detection in Very Noisy Conditions, by Philippe Renevey and Andrzej Drygajlo. http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.123.6098&rep=rep1&type=pdf

And this question covers the part of coding side of question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18962990/calculate-entropy-of-a-file